# Solutions for roof drainage with large amounts of water/ice?

Tags: concrete, drainage, gutters

My new shop is 30x60, single sloped the LONG way (water drains along 60 feet).  This is making for some large amounts of water coming off the end during storms, which makes washouts on the sloped gravel driveway that send gravel into my yard.  I have woods for the water to go off the corner of the shop, I just have to direct it there.  A gutter would be simplest, but the steel roof also gets BIG overhangs of ice as the snow/ice slowly melts/slides its way down in the spring- last year a 3 ft wide snow/ice overhang fell that weighted tons.  I suspect this would rip any gutter off.  I thought of a concrete apron out past the drip line, with a swale in it to direct the water sideways, or a trench drain at the drip line, but I ran a hose at various speed on the roof to test where the furthest drip line would be, and it varies by about 3 feet depending on how much water is running.  Any suggestions?

[image: Overview]
[image: Drip lines]

Comment: There are ice blockers for houses, but 60ft of ice/snow might just rip them and part of the off if the ice came down fast.  I am guessing moving those doors is out of the question.

Comment: The doors don't get used in the winter, so the ice doesn't bother me as long as it doesn't damage anything. But I want to redirect the water from storms and snow melt so it doesn't wash out my driveway.

Comment: Don't really need a "gutter", more of a low slope area to direct the water.  Might be called a swale.  A gentle dip instead of a hard drop.

Comment: Either the garage doors are on the wrong part of the building, or the roof is sloped the wrong way. Both are design problems.  The band-aid for the design problem is snow claws to keep the ice from moving until it melts, and gutters. The snow claws or other snow guard may have to go all the way up the roof.

Comment: That would rip any gutter off *that's made out of aluminum*. But not galvanized steel.... That stuff goes on your house, this stuff goes on commercial buildings. And put a gutter melter which is what that outlet is for.

Comment: Slope a concrete slab away from the garage with the slab covering the full range of drip lines plus a foot or two. Then terminate the slab with a big ol' trench drain. Make it 18" or 24" wide and fill it with 2" to 3" angular rocks so you can drive over it. I was originally thinking a skinnier trench, where "turfstone" concrete pavers could work as cheap top grating, but I just don't have any confidence that they wouldn't break. I also thought maybe 4" CMU blocks spanning the skinny way, but those skinny openings seem a little too small. I might even form something custom.

Comment: @popham the slab would have to be heated or it would become a glassy ice slope on many evenings.  Though OP said the doors aren't used in winter, it seems wrong to bake that even further into the design.

Comment: @jay613, the design prescription is simple: Prevent wash outs from storm runoff. A rake finish coupled with the naturally steep grade would avoid water freezing into a slippery hazard. I can easily imagine inoffensive boulders of ice sitting there for quite a while, though.

Comment: I would do what @popham suggested - 18"-24" french drain filled with rocks that can be driven over.  Only I would put this under the roof drip line, to divert the runoff before it can run down the slope.  This seems like the easiest/cheapest approach, and I would try try that before going with a full concrete slab.